# Square roots of $\mathbb R^{2n}$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

Recently, Richard Dore asked us [if $\mathbb R^3$ is the cartesian square of some space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space), and Tyler Lawson [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space/60378#60378) beautifully in the negative.

The even powers of $\mathbb R$ were left out in that question because, well, it is obvious that they are squares. Now:

> Are they squares in a unique way? In other words, if a space $X$ is such that $X\times X\cong\mathbb R^{2n}$, must $X$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?

One can consider other values of $2$ in Richard's question or here, as well as look for factors instead of only square roots (but if I recall correctly $\mathbb R^5$ has all exotic $\mathbb R^4$s as factors, so the last variant might be «trivial»...)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to attach interesting meaning to the statement «$\mathbb R^4$ is a square of $\mathbb R^2$ in only one way (up to some equivalence).»

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be no -- if I'm not making some elementary mistake I believe the product of two Whitehead manifolds is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^6$. 

Comment: But is seems that $\mathrm{(something\;which\;is\;not\;a\;manifold)}\times\mathbb R$ can be a manifold, so maybe the factors/square roots need not be manifolds themselves? 

Comment: Do you know any examples where $A \times B$ is a manifold, but neither $A$ nor $B$ is a manifold?  I can't think of any. 

Comment: @Ryan: That would be a nice follow-up question.

Comment: @Ryan I was just about to ask that question but the other way around: if $X$ is a connected manifold homeomorphic to $Y\times Z$, is it true that $Y$ and $Z$ are manifolds too?

Comment: @Olivier, it is not true: Wikipedia tells me that if $X=R^3/W$ is the result of contracting a standardly embedded Whitehead continuum $W\subseteq\mathbb R^3$, then $X$ is not a manifold yet $X\times\mathbb R$ is a copy of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: I think the square of any fake $R^4$ must be the standard $R^8$.

Comment: Yesterday while answering a question on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78055/ I found a result of Boals which implies that every $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ admits a square root that isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 3$, see Theorem 4.3 here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm68/fm68116.pdf

Comment: @Theo: my answer also gives such examples. 

Answer (score 28):

I'm pretty certain the answer is no provided $n \geq 3$.  Let $X$ be the Whitehead manifold: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold

It's a contractible open 3-manifold which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$.

$X^2$ I claim *is* homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^6$.  I don't have a slick proof of this.  The idea is, ask yourself if you can put a boundary on $X^2$ to make $X^2$ the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. Larry Siebenmann's dissertation says if $X^2$ is simply-connected at infinity, you're okay.   But the fundamental-group of the end of $X^2$ has a presentation of the form $(\pi_1 Y * \pi_1 Y) / <\pi_1 Y^2>$, where $*$ denotes free product and angle brackets "normal closure", and $\pi_1 Y$ is "the fundamental group at infinity for $X$".  So $\pi_1 X^2$ is the trivial group.

Once you have it as the interior of a compact manifold with boundary, the h-cobordism theorem kicks in and tells you this manifold is $D^6$.